# Android Gradle library dependency with library dependency using Nexus

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio

I'm switching my project over to using Gradle and an internal SonaType Nexus for hosting my dependencies. My core project depends on library project A and library project A has a dependency on library project B.

My issue is that as soon as I add LibA to my main project I get this error: 
"Module version com.example:LibA:1.1 depends on libraries but is not a library itself"

I have no issues adding library projects with jar dependencies with the same build script. I have seen people doing this successfully with LOCAL (in the project) android libraries but no one doing it with maven repos.

Is this a bug in gradle or did I misconfigure the library builds?

Core Project Build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
    }

    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile('com.example:LibA:1.+')
}
```

LibA Build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17

        versionCode = "3"
        versionName = "1.2"
    }

    android {
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aild.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile ('com.example:LibB:1.+')
    } ...
```

LibB Build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17

        versionCode = "1"
        versionName = "1.0"
    }

    android {
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aild.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
    } ...
```

Edit: Adding -info output for the error.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':GradleTest'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Module version com.example:LibA:1.+ depends on libraries but is not a library itself
```

Edit 2: Adding my local maven upload script for LibA

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

group = "com.example"
version = defaultConfig.versionName

configurations {
    archives {
        extendsFrom configurations.default
    }
}

signing {
    required { has("release") && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}


uploadArchives {
    configuration = configurations.archives
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }
        repository(url: sonatypeRepo) {
            authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername,
                    password: sonatypePassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name 'com-example'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'none'
            url 'https://internal github link'

            scm {
                url 'scm:git@https://internal github link'
                connection 'git@https://internal github link'
                developerConnection 'git@https://internal github link'
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'example'
                    url 'example'
                    distribution 'example'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'example'
                    name 'example'
                    email 'example'
                }
            }

            groupId "com.example"
            artifactId rootProject.name //LibA
            version defaultConfig.versionName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maven is rather unforgiving on spotty connections. Could you try deleting the m2 cache directory and giving it another go?

Comment: FWIW, Xav is looking into it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/frugpmBwQt0

Comment: FWIW, since my bounty didn't get a clear solution, I have posted another related SO question, trying to see if there's a working configuration we can use as a basis for determining where our trouble lies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551160/gradle-for-android-aar-depending-upon-aar-both-in-the-same-remote-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has gone away with the later versions of Gradle and the Android Gradle Plugin. Seems to have just been an early release bug.

Answer (score 2):

Your line in the dependencies to include LibA is wrong. To include a library project, use this:

```
compile project(':LibA')
```

If the library's directory isn't at the root of your project directory, you'll need to specify a colon-delimited path. For example, if your directory structure is:

```
projectFolder
  |
  +--coreProject
  |
  +--libraries
      |
      +--LibA
      |
      +--LibB
```

your dependency will be:

```
compile project(':libraries:LibA')
```

This is the same as the notation you use in your settings.gradle file.

Comment: As far as I know this is the method you would use for LOCAL dependencies, ie dependencies where the code is actually in the project structure. In my example I'm using remote dependencies pulled from mavencentral and a custom maven repo. My goal is to avoid local code in my project so that I don't need submodules to update them.

Comment: Oh, okay. Can you run the build from the command line and add the --info command-line option? That may shed more light on what's going wrong. It could be that your local Maven repo isn't set up right and Gradle can't find LibA. How have you set up that local Maven repo?

Comment: Yes the local maven repo works fine for all regular android libraries and jars. I only get the error message above when adding a library project that has another android library project as a dependency. Added -info error to original post.

Comment: How are you deploying LibA into the local Maven repo? If you're just trying to drop the library project into there, it won't work -- you have to configure your Gradle build script to deploy the AAR into the repo. There's some relevant info in http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html

Comment: I will post the code in the above post, let me know if you see errors.

Comment: As near as I can tell, this error happens when it grabbing the LibA dependency from your local Maven repo and it's not an AAR.

Comment: I went to my local repo and verified that the LibA aars are being published. They are there but perhaps something is still configured wrong in the LibA build file.

Comment: This is pretty much at the end of my knowledge without trying to actually debug the Android Gradle plugin itself.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe problem is that you use mavenCentral as your repository for library projects

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and not yours nexus repository where actual dependencies exists

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
}

    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you uploaded library artifact for both jar and aar, try this.

```
compile 'com.example:LibA:1.1.1@aar'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my work, I have used `compile project(':google-play-services_lib')` instead of `compile ('google-play-services_lib')` when I declare dependent projects in my build.gradle file. I think that is the right way to do this with Gradle: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:project_dependencies

Comment: These are maven hosted gradle projects not local source gradle projects, if you keep reading the section you linked you will see dependency declarations like that as well.

Comment: I see that. One more thing to try is list dependencies (http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#para:commandline_dependency_report) for each library project and then for core project and see the differences and debug.

Comment: I ran the command on the core project and it actually errors out with the same error when I try to build so I am not able to gather any additional information.

Comment: I saw Scott's post above aar files and it triggered my memory. Take a look at this post:http://www.flexlabs.org/2013/06/using-local-aar-android-library-packages-in-gradle-builds, it may help.

Comment: thanks for the link but I don't suffer this issue as my aars are actually already "remote" or served by maven (that's the custom nexus). The issue is what happens when I add libraries that have library dependencies. This just adds a single library dependency which is easy and working fine.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to have it as sub-module in the first build.gradle file you can add your local maven repository

mavenLocal()

```
//repositories
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
```

but you need to run install on libA first.

Comment: Luis, I'm pretty sure that using my custom maven repo is the exact same process as local maven - which would still produce the error I have above.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know for sure, just a couple of thoughts:

1. Have you tried running `gradle assemble` instead `gradle build`? This should skip tests, as I see error is related to test task.
2. Maybe stupid, but try to remove dependcy on 2nd lib from the first and put it to your main build file listing before the first. I have a memory of something related. This way the second lib may be added to classpath allowing the first to compile.
3. Try to create `.aar` files by hand and upload it to repo also by hand.
4. It's a hack, but maybe it'll work: have you considered to exclude this `:GradleTest` module? See [section 50.4.7](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec%3ahow_to_declare_your_dependencies)

Comment: Got the same error with assemble, I believe one of the projects is actually called GradleTest. 2) I have not tried yet... but that defeats the whole purpose of dependency management - my project should  not know about dependencies of the other projects.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message after introducing by mistake a **cyclic dependency** between libraries:

build.gradle in commons-utils

```
dependencies {
    ...
    instrumentTestCompile project(':test-utils')
}
```

build.gradle in test-utils

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':commons-utils')
}
```

Fixing this solved the problem. The error message is not very explicit.