# Uploading library on Maven central

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have added aar library to MavenCentral by going through [this toturial](http://www.vandalsoftware.com/post/52468430435/publishing-an-android-library-aar-to-a-maven)

When I add my library in project it gives me this error: **Module version MY_LIBRARY depends on libraries but is not a library itself**

You can find my build gradle file [here](https://gist.github.com/ikocijan/dedee03ed584716f6cbe)

I have a uploadArchives task in my build.gradle. Does anyone know why I get this error and how to fix it?

EDIT:

I figured out where was the problem. I had to add @aar in my build gradle file and now it's working. Example: compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti here is my build.gradle file https://gist.github.com/ikocijan/dedee03ed584716f6cbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out where was the problem. I had to add @aar in my build gradle file and now it's working. Example: compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'

Answer (score 2):

I already have this kind of problem with a cyclic dependency, so maybe you can check that.

I also found this, which is similar to your problem : [Android Gradle library dependency with library dependency using Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061652/android-gradle-library-dependency-with-library-dependency-using-nexus)

It seems that was an early release bug, so maybe you can try a more recent version of graddle.