# Android Gradle dependency local library using Nexus

Tags: android, gradle, sonatype, android-studio-2.0

I work on AndroidStudio,and I have a project that structure:

MyProject1

- |--- ModuleCommon
- |--- ModuleSocket(dependency ModuleCommon)
- |--- ModuleDemo

I want upload ModuleCommon and ModuleDemo to my local nexus service, I will use ModuleCommon or(and) ModuleSocket in other project, that my gradle script(fragment):

- ModuleCommon - build.gradle:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'maven'
def isReleaseBuild() {
    return VERSION_NAME.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
}
def getRepositoryUsername() {
    return hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
}
def getRepositoryPassword() {
    return hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""
}
afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                pom.groupId = GROUP
                pom.artifactId = "ModuleCommon"
                pom.version = "0.0.1"
                repository(url: RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL) {
                    authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
                }
                snapshotRepository(url: SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL) {
                    authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    }
    task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
    }
    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
    }
    artifacts {
        archives androidSourcesJar
        archives androidJavadocsJar
    }
}
```

- ModuleSocket - build.gradle:
  this snippet is same to ModuleCommon - build.gradle except dependencies:

```groovy
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile ('xmrk:rkandroid:0.0.1')
}
```

- MyProject1 - build.gradle:

```groovy
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        repositories {
            maven {url "http://192.168.1.34:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases"}
            maven {url "http://192.168.1.34:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"}
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        repositories {
            maven {url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases"}
            maven {url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"}
        }
    }
}
```

- gradle.properties:

```
GROUP=xmrk

SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL=http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/
RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL=http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/

NEXUS_USERNAME=myname
NEXUS_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Via above script, I upload my library ModuleCommon and ModuleSocket to my nexus server success, but when I use ModuleSocket, I obtain a error:

> Error:Failed to resolve: xmrk:ModuleCommon:unspecified
>   Open File
> Show in Project Structure dialog

Anybody save me? I feel my case like [Android Gradle library dependency with library dependency using Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061652/android-gradle-library-dependency-with-library-dependency-using-nexus), but have a bit diff, and have diff error.

Comment: Have you checked the nexus repo if xmrk:rkandroid exist?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Is exist, and I can use it, I edit dependencies to use it and I success

Comment: check the pom file, In particolar check the version of the artifact if it is 0.0.1 or unspecified.

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>xmrk</groupId>
<artifactId>ModuleSocket</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>aar</packaging>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>xmrk</groupId>
<artifactId>ModuleCommon</artifactId>
<version>0.+</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>   Is My POM in nexus of ModuleSocket, Is seems ok

Comment: Check the pom inside rkandroid artifact. Check if the dependency vs ModuleSocket is correct.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I can use ModuleCommon in other project, and i can use ModuleSocket via compile project(':ModuleSocket') in ModuleDemo, but I can't denpency it from nexus

Comment: I am not saying this. xmrk:ModuleCommon:unspecified means that you are using a dependency with ModuleCommon as dependency. In your build.gradle you are using compile ('xmrk:rkandroid:0.0.1'). May be the error is inside the pom file of the rkandroid module which can have a wrong dependency with ModuleCommon:unspecified

Comment: I'm sorry, the rkandroid == ModuleCommon, is my fault input above commant.  The pom is auto generate when I run Module's uploadArchives.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  Are you have guild or demo like my project?

Comment: Yes i have some situation like this. The issue that can occur is the pom file hasn't the vesion number in the dependency

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Orz...   I check my project again, pom of ModuleSocket,  the version of ModuleCommon is 0.+, and i checked my nexus repositories, ModuleCommon 0.0.1 is exists. And I can use ModuleCommon via compile 'xmrk:ModuleCommon:0.0.1' or compile 'xmrk:ModuleCommon:0.+'

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I resolve by delete C:\Users\[MyAccount]\.gradle\caches.  thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolve this question by delete cache in C:\Users[MyUsername].gradle\caches.

Thinks @Gabriele